# Continuity of a not so simple function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f_{x,y}:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $t \mapsto xt^{2} + yt$, and let $F(x,y) = \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} f_{x,y}(t)$. Say something about the continuity of the function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I started listing all the cases (when $x>0$ and $y>0$, $x>0$ and $y<0$, etc.) and taking limits to the right and left of $0$, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of solving this problem.

To summarize, the problem asks one to find where the function is continuous, discontinuous, and what type of discontinuity it has.

Comment: My apologies, the mistake has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any $x_0, y_0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, show that if $(x,y)$ is sufficiently close to $(x_0, y_0)$, $|f_{x,y}(t) - f_{x_0,y_0}(t)| < \epsilon$
for all $t \in [-1,1]$ (i.e. the functions $(x,y) \to f_{x,y}(t)$ for $t \in [-1,1]$ are equicontinuous).  This implies that for such $(x,y)$, 
$|F(x,y) - F(x_0, y_0)| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: @Lars note that for $G_t(x,y)=f_{x,y}(t)$ then $G_t$ is linear, so you need only prove continuity in $(0,0)$.